# How can I use wmic qfe get to format result to different columns of .csv file?

Tags: powershell

I am using the command `{wmic qfe get}` to get window update details.

I export the result to a `.csv` file, and I get all the column details in one column and not in different columns.

Can anybody help me with this? I want each heading (like csname, hotfix and description) to be shown in different column.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the textoutput to objects.

```
wmic qfe get /format:csv | ConvertFrom-Csv

Node     Caption                                    CSName   Description FixComments HotFixID  InstallDate InstalledBy
----     -------                                    ------   ----------- ----------- --------  ----------- -----------
FRODE-PC http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3021952 FRODE-PC Update                  KB3021952             NT AUTHOR...
FRODE-PC http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3036140 FRODE-PC Update                  KB3036140             NT AUTHOR...
....
```

Also, in PowerShell you can access wmi directly to get the original objects:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_quickfixengineering

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
FRODE-PC      Update           KB3021952     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
FRODE-PC      Update           KB3036140     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  02.05.2015 00.00.00
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have tried  /format:csv  i get all the data node,caption,csname etc all in one column ie the first column "A". I have tried Get-WmiObject win32_quickfixengineering but i dont get all dates in InstalledOn column , as i get in above wmic qfe get command .

Comment: WHERE do you first column A? It sounds like you're opening the csv file in Excel, and that is not PowerShell-related. `/format:CSV` gives you valid csv as you can see since I use `ConvertFrom-Csv` to convert the returned csv to objects. Are you sure about that? Considering that the data is retrieved using the exact same "database" called `WMI`.

Comment: I think some problem somewhere... Just checking ... will get back after that . Thanks :-)

Comment: I am trying the commmand
    `wmic qfe get /format:csv | ConvertFrom-Csv`
and get back 
     `Invalid XSL format (or) file name.`
what may be the issue?

Comment: Why use `wmic` wth text-output + converting when you can use the `get-wmiobject` solution that uses wmi directly in PowerShell.